# System.ApplicationException: 'EPSG PCS/GCS code 4326 not found in EPSG support files. Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?'

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile, geojson, convert

I have setup a consol app in C# that uses the GDAL.CORE NuGet,
it seems to work fine when converting most of the .shp files I have,
however with one .shp file I am getting the error below:

```
System.ApplicationException: 'EPSG PCS/GCS code 4326 not found in EPSG support files. 
Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?'
```

I am using the gcs.csv file below which seems to include this coordinate code = 4326

[image]

Also I have setup the path to my gdal-data correctly, so I know its reading my gcs.csv file.

```
Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-data");
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What does ogrinfo print about the coordinate reference system of that shapefile?

Comment: How can I get ogrinfo in C# code ? this is what I am currently doing                  
string shapefilePath = dataDir + "\\Manchester.shp";
string jsonPath = dataDir + "/output_out_GDALCORE.json";
Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", "C:\\Program Files\\GDAL\\gdal-data");
OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.RegisterAll();           
OSGeo.OGR.Driver shpDriver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");
DataSource shpDatasource = shpDriver.Open(shapefilePath, 0);

Comment: Use binaries, I just want to see information about the source data and if is looks exceptional.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply !!, I just had a look and there is nothing unusual, can't really attach it to this post though, any other suggestions ?

Comment: Make a copy with ogr2ogr `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -a_srs epsg:4326 output.shp input.shp`. Does your code show the same exception with the copy?

Comment: sure, let me try converting the copied shape file

Comment: Hi I just created a copy of the original shape file in my C# consol app >>   DataSource shpDatasourceCreateCopy = shpDriver.CopyDataSource(shpDatasource, dataDir + "\\CopyTest", new string[0]);  and this sorts out the issue !! thanks a lot for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is sorted after creating a copy of the original shape file and running the conversion against the copied shape file.

C# consol app >>   `DataSource shpDatasourceCreateCopy = shpDriver.CopyDataSource(shpDatasource, dataDir + "\\CopyTest", new string[0]);`

Comment: Now it might be possible for you to find the real reason for the issue. Something is different in the original than in the copy.